# Increasing swap by reallocating it to SSD

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, swap, disk

I currently have 64GB swap on the SSD that also has my main file system. There is no unallocated space to increase the swap. I need more swap for machine learning problems.

Can I reallocate the swap to a different SSD, which has more capacity, without damaging my system?

I have found several posts about setting up swap when none is present, but they don't address editing a current swap setup.

Thank you.

Comment: Does "ML" means "memory leak"?

Comment: You can just add more swap partitions or swap devices with `swapon`. There is no need to have one big swap partition or file.

Comment: Sorry, machine learning.

Comment: So, just add a second on a different SSD and they will both be used as required?

Comment: 64Gb as swap? Why? "Can I reallocate the swap to a different SSD, which has more capacity, without damaging my system?" Ofcours. swap before 17.04 is a partition. So turn swapoff, remove it and turn swapon on the new location. In 17.04 it is actually a file /swapfile with a reference in /etc/fstab.

Comment: If you need swap for temporary use, you can make a swap file. but if you are going to use your SSD all the time as swap, you can introduce it as swap partition in `/etc/fstab`. Have a look on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXhcnoVPpHQ)

Comment: "Why?". Because my machine learning algos require more than 128GB of RAM.